# Prevent multiple queued events from being triggered by EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I have two instances of a class `MyWorker`. I bind the `start` method of these objects to the `start` event. And there is an array of items to be processed. I assign one item to each object and `emit` the `start` event.

```
for (i = 0; i < objs.length; i += 1) {
  objs[i].item = items.shift();
}

self.emit('start');
```

The start method has some async IO job in it, so everything works fine. And after processing the object emits a `done` event. The `done` method checks if `items.length > 0`. If yes, it assigns the next item to the same object and emits the `start` event.

```
MyClass.prototype.done = function (data) {
  var self = this;

  data.object.item = items.shift();
  self.emit('start');
}
```

Now, consider a case where there is very little IO wait time, or event no IO operation. All goes synchronously. In this case, the `done` event will be fired even before the next object has got `start` event. The `done` will assign new object and emit `start` again. This is what creates the problem. The `start` of second object will now be called twice.

Any idea how to address this?

Comment: Yes, real problem, I event experience this when there is a very short IO wait time

Comment: I'm trying to understand the setup. So 1 array with work items and 2 workers which need to process each item in the array once ?

Comment: they process one item at a time

Comment: On `emit('start')`, the `EventEmitter` calls each listener in a `for` loop. So, the next listener will only be called if the first goes into IO. But in my case, it doesn't get time to call the second listener.

Comment: Of course I have the same issue with n number of worker. This number is configurable. I create workers dynamically. I just explained the problem with two workers because the problem occurs when workers are more than one.

Comment: Is there a need to use event emitters to solve this problem? Have you looked at Async.js to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at alternatives. I can even use the direct method call like `objs[i].start.call(objs[i])`. However, this is a problem worth giving some thoughts. That's why asked the question.

Comment: I disagree, I'm with @AndyD, this isn't a problem "worth giving thoughts", this is a case of a misused piece of the language, which should be avoided.  What you have is called a "race condition", just because you can expect I/O to happen slowly, doesn't mean you should depend on that as time for registering your event handlers.  In order to see the "best solution" I believe we would need more context on the problem, my intuition suggests that you're doing some initialization that would best be done with sync calls, or a series of callbacks, rather than event emitters/handlers.

Comment: You are right, you would need more context on the problem. May be that's why you think this is a misused piece of the language. Nevermind, I found a way out. Appreciate the inputs.